# why my rendered animation is not working properly?

Tags: rendering

I am trying to compile my render png's into a complete animation but they are performing differently and I have no idea why. If you can help then please do. here is the link of my blender file https://pasteall.org/media/e/d/ed1c10c43d0febb896c78814107b9864.blend

Comment: although i opened you blend file i have no idea what you mean!? could you pls elaborate a bit more what you want to do? what happens? and what should result?

Comment: I've tried a rendering and I don't see any difference, could you please elaborate as Chris asked?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.